# How do we solve the quotation inside of a quotation problem while using django?

Tags: html, django

I can't use the same type of string in the same type of string in HTML

I have a static folder in the root dierctory of my django project and I was changing a downloaded template's link to match the django project.

Here is the HTML attribute
`style="background-image: url(\"{% static 'assets/img/why-us.png' %}\")"`

as you can see I tried using backslash () to resolve the problem but it was no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely change the inner double-quotes to single-quotes to avoid nesting the same type of quotes since the Django template engine replaces what's inside `{% ... %}` with the output from its execution, so the single-quotes inside `{% ... %}` would not cause any conflicts with the HTML/CSS parser:

```
style="background-image: url('{% static 'assets/img/why-us.png' %}')"
```

Comment: That didn't solve my problem